# R - download de dados municipais do IBGE

Tags: r, download

Existe alguma maneira de fazer download de dados municipais do IBGE com linha de comando do R?

Comment: O ibge tem uma página de API. Veja https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/docs. Tem uma série de informações lá.

Answer (score 4):

Se você conhece o link de download você pode tentar utilizar a função `download.file` para baixar qualquer tipo de arquivo na internet, neste [link](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/download.file.html) você encontra um help dos argumentos que podem ser usados, e neste [site](http://rfunction.com/archives/2222) tem um exemplo prático de uso.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que hoje o trabalho do Anthony Damico é o mais completo sobre a leitura de diversas fontes de dados. No site dele é possível encontrar desde o script do donwload, passando pela leitura e chegando na análise, usando pacotes como o Survey. Recomendo fortemente a visita:
http://www.asdfree.com.

Em particular, sobre o Censo Demográfico Brasileiro tem o seguinte link:
http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/censo%20demografico%20no%20brasil%20%28censo%29

Para chegar em um resultado mais preciso o Anthony contou com a colaboração do Prof. Djalma Pessoa, atualmente aposentado do IBGE.

Comment: @leadromarino, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Sua resposta está bacana mas, é recomendado transcrever, mesmo que somente as partes mais importantes dos links, para que sua resposta permaneça válida mesmo se os links estiverem quebrados. Dê uma olhada em [answer] e [tour] se tiver qualquer dúvida

Comment: @Caputo Compreendo. Na realidade fiz esta opção visto que a resposta não é tão trivial, bem como os scripts. Vou estar mais atento à isto. Obrigado!